Undefined symbols: _OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTC...in Quickblox SDK iOS swift


We are having this issue using M1 Laptop arm64:
https://github.com/QuickBlox/ios-quickblox-sdk.git
https://github.com/QuickBlox/ios-quickblox-sdk-webrtc.git
with swift package manager. We are unable to use rosetta so that's not an option.
as you see we are using latest version as of this writing.
any possible solutions?
